# iOS building custom rating control issue

Tags: ios, debugging, uibutton

I know there's lots of 3rd party solutions out there, but I've decided to build one myself to be in full control of the animations and to learn something new.

It seems like most of the time it is made through subclassing UIControl and tracking touches, but I've used a different approach. I create system buttons with images. This way I get a nice highlight animation on a press for free. Anyway, it works quite nice until you press on it really fast. Here's a gif of what's happening.

[image]

Sometimes, if you do it really fast a full star gets stuck. I'll try to explain what's happening behind this animation. Since full and empty stars have different color, I change tint color of the button each time i becomes full or empty. The animation you see is a separate UIImageView that is added on top of the button right before the beginning of the animation block and is removed in the completion block. I believe sometimes on emptying the star animation is not fired and image is not removed in the completion block. But I can't catch this bug in code.

I added some debugging code to see if the block that makes a star empty is even fired. Seems like it is, and even completion block is called.

```
2015-04-23 13:00:00.416 RERatingControl[24011:787202] 
Touch number: 5
2015-04-23 13:00:00.416 RERatingControl[24011:787202] 
removing a star at index: 4
2015-04-23 13:00:00.693 RERatingControl[24011:787202] star removed
```

Star indexes are zero-based, so the 5th star is supposed to be removed, but it's not.

Full project is on [github](https://github.com/NKorotkov/RERatingControl). It's pretty small. I would appreciate if someone would help me fix this. Oh, and feel free to use this code if you want to :-)

**UPDATE.** I was suggested to post some logic code here. I didn't do it right away because I felt it would be too cumbersome.

**Button action method:**

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {


static int touchNumber = 0;
NSLog(@"\nTouch number: %d", touchNumber);
touchNumber++;

if (self.isUpdating) {

    return;
}

self.updating = YES;
NSInteger index = [self.stars indexOfObject:sender];
__block NSTimeInterval delay = 0;

[self.stars enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    REStarButton *btn = (REStarButton*)obj;

    if (idx <= index) {

        if (!btn.isFull) {

            NSLog(@"\nadding a star at index: %ld", (long)idx);
            [btn makeFullWithDelay:delay];
            delay += animationDelay;

        }

    } else {

        if (btn.isFull) {

            NSLog(@"\nremoving a star at index: %ld", (long)idx);
            [btn makeEmptyWithDelay:0];
        }

    }

}];

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ratingDidChangeTo:)]) {

    [self.delegate ratingDidChangeTo:index + 1];

}


self.updating = NO;

}
```

**Empty a full star method:**

```
- (void)makeEmptyWithDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay {

//    if (!self.isFull) {
//        return;
//    }

    self.full = NO;

    UIImageView *fullStar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.starImageFull];
    [self addSubview:fullStar];

    CGFloat xOffset = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMidX(fullStar.bounds);
    CGFloat yOffset = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMidY(fullStar.bounds);

    fullStar.frame = CGRectOffset(fullStar.frame, xOffset, yOffset);

    [self setImage:self.starImageEmpty forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self setTintColor:self.superview.tintColor];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        //fullStar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1f, 0.1f);

        fullStar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 10);
        fullStar.alpha = 0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [fullStar removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"star removed");

    }];
```

**Make an empty star full method:**

```
}

- (void)makeFullWithDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay {


//    if (self.isFull) {
//        return;
//    }

    self.full = YES;

    UIImageView *fullStar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.starImageFull];


    CGFloat xOffset = CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMidX(fullStar.bounds);
    CGFloat yOffset = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMidY(fullStar.bounds);

    fullStar.frame = CGRectOffset(fullStar.frame, xOffset, yOffset);
    fullStar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01f, 0.01f);
    [self addSubview:fullStar];

    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:animationDuration delay:delay options:0 animations:^{

        CGFloat ratio = 0.35;

        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:ratio animations:^{
            fullStar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(animationScaleRatio, animationScaleRatio);
        }];

        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:ratio relativeDuration:1 - ratio animations:^{
            fullStar.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [self setImage:self.starImageFull forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setTintColor:self.fullTintColor];

        [fullStar removeFromSuperview];

    }];

}
```

Comment: it would be good if you post the related codes here. looks like a logic problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I've managed to find a reason behind my bug and it works perfect now!

I used View Debugging to see if it's an UIImageView from animation is stuck on the button or the image of button itself is not set properly. I was surprised to see it's the button image that causing the issue. And then I looked through code again and realised I was changing the button image in the completion block after delay with no regard to if it's state has already changed. A simple fix to makeFullWithDelay: solved my issue.

```
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    if (self.isFull) {

        [self setImage:self.starImageFull forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setTintColor:self.fullTintColor];

    }

    [fullStar removeFromSuperview];

}];
```

I used whole evening trying to find the answer yesterday, and after I posted the question answer came by itself. Telling people about your problem really helps to go through your logic with more attention I guess. Thanks to everyone :-)

Should I delete the post or it might help someone in the future?